# Evaluating the Gauss Circle Problem $N(n)$ in $O(n^{\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon})$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, convex-hulls

I'm interested in the technique of counting the number of positive integer pairs $x$ and $y$ satisfying $x^2+y^2 \leq n$ in $O(n^{\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon})$. The basic idea is that we can only focus on the convex hull of the integer lattice points falling in the circle $x^2+y^2 \leq n$ and the number of vertices of such convex hull is $O(n^\frac{1}{3})$. By trying to find the lattice points on the convex hull quickly (in roughly amortized constant time), we are able to yield the answer in $O(n^{\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon})$. Though there is a program implementing such an idea together with the stern-brocot tree, it is still quite hard to follow. Any detail/thought/explanation on the solution is welcome.

A related problem is [here](https://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVCNT1/), which uses essentially the same technique to find out the convex hull of the integer lattice points under the hyperbola.

Meanwhile, a proof of the number of integer lattice points of the convex hull is $O(n^\frac{1}{3})$ is also appreciated.

Comment: Solutions of problems of Project Euler should not be discussed in public (except problems with numbers up to 100, to teach fundamental concepts).

Comment: @NoNames: but isn't it a *different* problem?

Comment: This is NOT the problem in Project Euler. Rather, it is a different problem proposed in the forum.

Comment: Please notice that not everyone has access to the discussion thread that you are linking to. Only those having solved Problem 540 get the access. Besides, I believe that this question still may be a spoiler to this Project Euler problem. My suggestion is to post your question (without spoiler) on https://projecteuler.chat and ask if someone could discuss with you through private messages.

Comment: I've deleted the link. Please focus on the technique and discuss the technical details.

Comment: Why did you refer to that special problem, then? It's not in that forum by accident, and your reference is a hint, already. Moreover, your "Any detail/thought/explanation on the solution is welcome" seems to refer to the solution of that problem. Concerning the number of lattice points in the convex hull, a simple proof is here: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62183